# Running itself multithreaded functions on a dask cluster

Tags: dask

I have some function which uses image processing functions which are itself multithreaded. I distribute many of those function calls on a dask cluster.
First, I started a scheduler on a host: `dask-scheduler`. The I started the workers: `dask-worker --nthreads 1 --memory-limit 0.9 tcp://scheduler:8786`.

The python code looks similar to this:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

def func(filename):
    sitk.ProcessObject.SetGlobalDefaultNumberOfThreads(4)  # limit to four threads
    img = sitk.ReadImage(filename)
    # Do more stuff and store resulting image 
    # SimpleITK is already multithreaded
    return 'someresult'


# [...]
from distributed import Client
client = Client('tcp://scheduler:8786')

futures = client.map(func, ['somefile', 'someotherfile'])
for result in client.gather(futures):
    print(result)
```

Right now, I have to set the number of threads for each worker to one, in order not to overcommit the CPU on the worker node. But in some cases it makes sense to limit the number of cores used by SimpleITK, because the gain is not so high. Instead, I could run multiple function calls in parallel on the same host.
But in that case I would have to calculate all the core usages by hand.
Ideally, I would like to set an arbitrary number of cores each function can use and dask should decide how many parallel functions invocations are started on each node, given the number of available threads. I.e. is it possible to specify the number of threads a function will use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Dask is not able to either limit the number of threads spawned by some function, and doesn't attempt to measure this either.

The only thing I could think you might want to do is use Dask's [abstract rsources](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html), where you control how much of each labelled quantity is available per worker and how much each task needs to run.

```
futures = client.map(func, ['somefile', 'someotherfile'], resources=...)
```

I don't see an obvious way to assign resources to workers using `Cluster()` (i.e., the default `LocalCluster`), you may need to use the CLI.